# How to check rolify with a helper in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

I want to make some helpers for my rolify methods.

So, I've created the following:

#### Users helper

module UsersHelper

```
    #Check if current user is admin

    def admin_check
      if current_user
      if current_user.has_role? :admin
     end
    end

    #Check if current user is pro and admin

    def admin_and_pro_check
      if current_user
      if current_user.has_any_role? :admin, :pro
     end
    end

    #Check if current user is pro

    def pro_check
      if current_user
      if (current_user.has_role? :pro) && (current_user.is_pro == true)
     end
    end
  end

end
```

Now, in my view, how do I use them? Which is the better way?

```
<%= pro_check do %>
  <%= f.input :url, label: "Visto en", placeholder: "www.paginaweb.com" %>
<% end %>

<%= if pro_check %>
  <%= f.input :url, label: "Visto en", placeholder: "www.paginaweb.com" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add these to the user model. The downside being being if you keep adding roles, this could get pretty unmaintainable.
It will make it much nicer to work with and make the truth checks much more readable.

I would also use the Null Object Pattern in your current_user method so you can avoid all of the nil checks. I hate repeated nil checks, but if you're fine with them, then totally ignore this advice.

The `if` checks in your code are for the most part unnecessary as you will see below.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  def pro?
    self.has_role?(:pro) && self.is_pro == true
  end

  def admin?
    self.has_role? :admin
  end
end
```

at this point you could either return a user instance or a Null Object (like the one illustrated in avdi's post here http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/05/30/null-objects-and-falsiness/) in your current_user method
or if you're using devise, you could just embed your pro check in a `user_signed_in?` check

here is the devise example

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <% if current_user.pro? %>
    User is a pro
  <% elsif current_user.admin? %>
    User is an admin
  <% elsif current_user.admin? && current_user.pro? %>
    Current user is an admin and a pro
  <% else %>
    Current user is neither an admin nor a pro
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You could of course create your own `user_logged_in?` method that checked for current user existing if you aren't using devise. I think it is a nice readable method name. You could put it in `application_helper.rb`

Answer (score 1):

Your methods don't return anything. You want a method that returns true or false, I'd recommend:

```
def admin_check
  current_user && current_user.has_role?(:admin)
end

def admin_and_pro_check
  current_user && current_user.has_any_role?(:admin, :pro)
end

def pro_check
  current_user && current_user.has_role?(:pro) && current_user.is_pro == true
end
```

Then you can use then like you have in your view.